# Objects with different possible data types in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, polymorphism

I want to store object in DB using Entity Framework and I want them to store some data and some header stuff. The first draft looks something like this:

```
class ResourceAttribute
{
    string AttributeName;
    DataType DataType;

    string StringValue;
    float? FloatValue;
    int? IntValue;

    string DefaultStringValue;
    float? DefaultFloatValue;
    int? DefaultIntValue;
}
```

Now this seems like really bad design. Is there a better way to represent a data structure like this?

Maybe something like this:

```
class ResourceAttribute<T>
{
    string AttributeName;
    T Value;
    T DefaultValue;
}
```

Or maybe some type of subclassing with different types of values. But that seems like it would lead to other problems.

What is the best way to represent data like this?

Comment: You want to set the default value or the type default ?

Comment: I want the ResourceAttribute class to represent data that has exactly one value that might have different data types (string, int or float) as well as some other data that is always there like Name. The default value is not that important for the example, it's there to illustrate the ugliness of the first approach

Comment: What sort of types are we talking about, Just simple primitive types , or complex classes

Comment: I'm just using simple primitives

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to achieve so, one of the ways to store all as string then parse them by Convert Class For ex :

```
class ResourceAttribute{
    string AttributeName;
    string Value;
    string DefaultValue;
    Public T GetValue<T>()
    {
      try {
          return Convert.ChangeType(number, typeof(T));
      }
      catch (InvalidCastException) {
         Console.WriteLine("Cannot convert");
         return default(T); // Or you can return your default value obj
      }

    }
}
```

Like this you can convert to any format you need by passing the datatype you require. And all values will be stored as strings in DB.

Answer (score 0):

When i came across similar kind of problem, i just use `object`,

```
public class ResourceAttribute
{
   string AttributeName;
   string DataType;
   object StringValue;
   object DefaultStringValue;
}
```